# Декодировать base64 из строки вида data:image/jpeg;base64,

Tags: php

Есть изображение

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2Qt.....

Есть ли какой-нибудь более красивый способ получить mime тип файла(из коробки), а не разбивать строку по частям?
Пробую делать так

```
$fileinfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileinfo->buffer(base64_decode('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA....'));
```

Но он мне возвращает, что mime тип изображения "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
base64_decode('data:image/jpeg;base64,...
```

Декодирует полную абракадабру, которая действительно "application/octet-stream". Чтобы вы получили настоящий тип для данных, нужно декодировать сами данные. Например, так:

```
$decoded = base64_decode(substr($str, strpos($str, ',') + 1));
```

В качестве оптимизации можно пробовать декодировать только первые сто байт от картинки, но тут могут быть неизвестные подводные камни.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это то, что мне было нужно.